# Generate part codes based on multiple variable constraints

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate thousands of unique descriptive stock codes based on a number of varying constraints in a consistent way. So for example product group a is defined by a material, gauge, girth, folds, and taper. There are a variable number of each on of these categories - as in there are 2 unique materials, 10 unique gauges, 20 unique girths, 10 unique folds, and they are tapered or not. So for example a product code should look like: MAT11.001100G7FTY, which is material 1, 1.00 gauge, 1100 girth, 7 fold, tapered.

Another example of a product group b is constrained by the material, gauge, product type (there are multiple product types in group b), length, width and height. So an example code would be MAT11.25SUMP800Lx900Wx700H, which is material 1, 1.25 gauge, sump, 800 long, 900 wide, 700 high.

All combinations utilising all constraints need to be generated. So ABCDE is a part code, but ACE is not.

The constraint data is simple enough that I can manipulate it into whatever form is required. Currently I have each product group separate and then one constraint type per column and all of the possible options for that constraint as the rows. As per the below

I have a basic understanding of VBA but am struggling with the best solution for this problem. Should I be generating arrays of each constraint and then concatenating every value in each array with each other value? Or a multi dimension array? Or should I be iterating down all of the rows and all columns and writing the values directly to the column that will store the final values directly, without storing them in a variable at some point along the way

The final outcome I need is a single column with one part code per row.

EDIT: Here is the constraint data and my current code - this is currently functional, but the number of arrays and size of the arrays are hard-coded. Is there a way I can generalise this?

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim m(0 To 1) As String 'material array
    Dim g(0 To 18) As String 'girth array
    Dim f(0 To 9) As String 'fold array
    Dim t(0 To 1) As String 'taper array

    Dim mItem As Variant 'material array element
    Dim gItem As Variant 'girth array element
    Dim fItem As Variant 'fold array element
    Dim tItem As Variant 'taper array element

    Dim i As Integer 'for iterating

    For i = 0 To 1
        m(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value 'store materials in material array
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 18
        g(i) = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value 'store girth in material array
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 9
        f(i) = Cells(i + 1, 3).Value 'store folds in material array
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 1
        t(i) = Cells(i + 1, 4).Value 'store taper in material array
    Next i

    'reset iteration to row 1
    i = 1

    'loop through each arary and concatate values
    For Each mItem In m()
        For Each gItem In g()
                For Each fItem In f()
                    For Each tItem In t()

                        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & mItem 'write material value to result col
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & gItem 'write girth value to result col
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & fItem 'write fold value to result col
                        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value & tItem 'write taper value to result col

                        i = i + 1 'next row
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I've updated my question as requested. I now have functional code but cannot work out how to generalise it?